# SqlDataReader "Enumeration yielded no results"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

Been trying to figure out, but I can't.

I execute a Stored Procedure via SqlCommand and the SqlDatareader object that is returned doesn't give me the results, however, I can see them if a explore the object in the debugger. here's an image of what I'm talking about:

### [image: See the "Result view" row]

In the Result View row it says "**Enumeration yielded no results**" but in the path:

**base -> base -> ResultView -> [0] -> Non-Public members -> _values -> [0],[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OzVq.png),[2],[3]**
the results are shown.

Anyone has an idea how to get them?

This is the code I'm using to get and specific column:

```
if (dataReader.Read())
{
   ProjectFolderId = dataReader["ItemID"].ToString();
}
```

but the **if** is returning false.

Comment: Having same issue. Any solution ?

Answer (score 10):

You need to be careful: a reader can only be consumed **once**. By having the data visible in the preview window, it is entirely likely you've consumed that data accidentally in the debugger, and it is no longer available.

Make sure it is **not** visible/expanded in a debugger preview window, and try again.

The `_values` shown is just the legacy/remains of the last row that was successfully read.

Comment: How I can make them not visible? Btw, I executed the query without the Stored Procedure (direct in the CommandText property and then ExecuteSelect) and now is working. I believe is something odd with the proccess using Stored Procedures, what you think?

Comment: @equasar I doubt it relates to stored procedures - beyond setting the command-type, the API is identical; usually, you need to electively click to expand an enumeration, because the IDE knows that many are non-repeatable. Did you maybe click to expand it?

Comment: You rock, @MarcGravell. I can't believe the debugger consumes the data.