# Why is DataReader giving "Enumeration Yielded No Results"?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using a very simple stored procedure that has 2 parameters. It then fills up a DataReader, but when I run the code, the DataReader throws an error saying "Enumeration yielded no results" despite making it past the reader.Read() line.

My function is passed email as a parameter. It then establishes the connection:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IdesignTriviaConnection"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetCurrentLink", con);
            SqlDataReader reader;

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 100).Value = DateTime.Today;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = email;
```

After this it opens the connection and establishes the reader:

```
try
            {
                if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                }
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    long LinkID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    String URL = reader.GetString(1);
                    long Completed = reader.GetInt32(2);

if (LinkID == 0)
                    {
                        link = "0";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Completed == 1)
                        {
                            link = "1";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            link = URL;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

As stated, the stored procedure works perfectly in query analyzer and I've even used the debugger to see that it is actually returning the expected values of:

So where am I going wrong here? Why, if the datareader is failing to enumerate any data, is it making it past the reader.Read() line? Why am I am I able to see that data in the debugger if I so choose?

Comment: Do you have a watch in the debugger on `reader` or something that would enumerate the reader outside your code?

Comment: Can you show more of your code, is there anything after the last line `long Completed = reader.GetInt32(2);`? We need to see the whole `while` loop. Also, you are not putting your reader in a `using` block, nor your `SqlConnection`, this will cause performance problems if you put those two in `using` blocks once you do get your code working.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Is the error coming form your code or the debugger?

Comment: How many result sets does the proc return? Does the proc use `SET NOCOUNT ON`?

Comment: No watch set on anything. The line of code throwing the exception is long LinkID = reader.GetInt32(0). The error comes when running the code. The proc returns one result set and yes, SET NOCOUNT ON is set.

Comment: 1) long != Int32. A `long` is an `Int64` / `BIGINT`. So either change `long` to be `int` OR change `GetIn32` to be `GetInt64`, whichever is appropriate. 2) you have `Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 100)` yet DateTime does not have a length component, so remove the `, 100` from there. If that doesn't help, you need to post the code to `usp_GetCurrentLink`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: SqlDataReader “Enumeration yielded no results” (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117343/sqldatareader-enumeration-yielded-no-results). Best regards,

Comment: I added the rest of the procedure. There is just one datareader. I also made the other changes suggested and nothing.

Comment: Alex, I saw that post yesterday and that is NOT what is happening in my case. I found the problem because the code ran in an unexpected way. Yes, there have been times when I have stopped and peeked at the data (which probably causes the reader to freak out), but most of the time I have a break set at the long LinkID = reader.GetInt64(0) line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the answer was to remove the length from the date parameter. That's what I get for copying and pasting and not noticing that issue. Even though it was returning the data, apparently the datareader thought there was no data. Thanks to those who suggested that fix.

Answer (score 0):

I got that error from spelling the columnName wrong. I changed from

```
string stn_nm = _rdr["STN_NAME"].ToString();
```

to

```
string stn_nm = _rdr["STATION_NAME"].ToString(); //correct
```

Then, no more that error!

So, the easiest thing to check first is, all the spellings for your columns. Good luck!