# SqlDataReader - Enumeration yielded no results

Tags: c#, sql-server

During execution of this code reader shows "Enumeration yielded no results" and the method return empty model. I have no idea what's wrong

```
 public UserModel GetUser(string email)
    {
        email = email.ToString();
        var connection = OpenConnection();
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "select * from Users where UserName = @email;";
        AddParameterString(command, "@email", email);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        UserModel model = new UserModel();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            model.ConfirmedEmail = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["ConfirmedEmail"]);
            model.UserId = int.Parse(reader["userId"].ToString());
            model.UserName = reader["UserName"].ToString();
            model.UserEmail = reader["UserEmail"].ToString();
            model.PasswordHash = reader["PasswordHash"].ToString();
            model.PasswordSalt = reader["PasswordSalt"].ToString();
            model.UserRole = reader["UserRole"].ToString();
        }
        return model;
    }
}



 protected void AddParameterString(SqlCommand command, string parameterName, string value)
    {
        var newParameter = command.CreateParameter();
        newParameter.ParameterName = parameterName;
        newParameter.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
        newParameter.Value = value;
        command.Parameters.Add(newParameter);
    }
```

Comment: List field names explicitly in `select` statement. Chances are that some name is mistyped.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Enumeration yielded no results means that the reader is empty.

Comment: `while(reader.Read())` means that OP enter the inner block and at least one row exists.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev The OP never stated that the while block got executed.

Comment: Most probably the error comes from `Convert.ToBoolean(reader["ConfirmedEmail"]);`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600370/why-is-datareader-giving-enumeration-yielded-no-results

Comment: Is the problem really the reader? What ix you execute scalar? Does that return a value?

Answer (score 1):

The @ symbol is not required when naming a parameter (see: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)

```
AddParameterString(command, "email", email);
```

Answer (score 0):

AddParameterString(command, "@email", email); // Remove this line

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email); // Add this line