# datareader has rows but shows Enumeration yielded no results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader

i use `SqlDataReader` to read data from query result,i run the debugger and the query is working. hasrows is true, but it shows Enumeration yielded no results.

this is my code :

```
SqlCommand selectLastData = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbl_transaksi ORDER BY id DESC", conn);
using (SqlDataReader rdr = selectLastData.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
           string id = rdr["id"].ToString();

        }
        rdr.Close();
    }
}
```

[image]
anyone can help? thank you

Comment: Did you mean to comment out the `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: no i have edited the question, i mean the rdr hasrows but data is empty

Comment: @Mamen: please explain what's going on, what means "data is empty"?

Comment: can you please provide exception and stack trace here?

Comment: the HasRows property is showing true value it means there is some data within it, but the ResultView is showing Enumeration yielded no results and the while is skipped.

Comment: @MihirDave there is no error

Comment: @Mamen: what _ResultView_? A `SqlDataReader` is not a LINQ query. Output the `id` in the loop and you will see it: `Console.WriteLine(id);`

Comment: @TimSchmelter i add the picture of my error, the loop even not executed

Comment: @MihirDave the data is available in database there are 7 rows

Comment: there are 7 records in table @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: The `id` variable is never used, do you know if it is ever written to; have debugged and stepped into the while loop and seen if the code is executed? Maybe the error is that you never use the value? By the way, you should really use, `ExecuteScalar()` method instead of `ExecuteReader()` when your purpose is to read a single value

Comment: See this discussion and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20275727/8695782

Comment: @Mamen what happens when control reaches to dr.Read() ?

Comment: @MihirDave it skipped the loop and goes to rdr.Close()

Comment: I have close voted already because it was unclear, but this is the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117343/sqldatareader-enumeration-yielded-no-results Maybe someone else can close-vote it as dup.

Comment: @mortb the executescalar also return null

Comment: Remove all existing breakpoints and watch window entries. Add a breakpoint to `string id = rdr["id"].ToString();` Run the code. Do you hit the breakpoint (don't guess, give it a try).

Comment: What if you run the code directly without any breakpoints? Does print anything in Console?

Comment: no it doesnt hit id @mjwills

Comment: Have you run the query in sql server management studio, against the same database? If you do, are there any rows returned? Are you sure you are using the correct connection string so you're not connected to a database where the table is empty?

Comment: Off topic: [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) also implements `IDisposable` so it should be in a `using` statement too.

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
While(rdr.read()){
//Read your Columns values using Id or Name Here..
}
```

read() function allows to read the populated data from database.